# SQL error: A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded

Tags: sql-server, multithreading

I am using VS Studio 2105 / SSMS 2014 v 12.0.410. Using VB.net.

I am running a console app that does polling on the 0 and 30 second mark. It will do this 24 by 7. As part of the process, a background thread is spawned. (See explanation below).

The database connection string is:

```
add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=xxxxx,14334;Database=xxx_dev;Uid=xxx_dev;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

The class and its functions called for open and close:

```
Dim strConnectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConnectionString")

Sub OpenDB()
    If objConn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
        objConn.Close()
    End If

    objConn.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
    objConn.Open()
    objCmd.Connection = objConn

    objCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
End Sub

Sub CloseDB()
    objConn.Close()
End Sub
```

[image]

I customized the error message to get all that I could about it.

> A severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded. --> State: 0 --> Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider --> Error number: 0 --> Line number: 0 --> Line number: -2146232060 --> Class: 11 --> Procedure: --> Call stack: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at ReliableSiteBandwidthPollingTester.Module1.SaveBandwidthPollingLog(Switch SaveSwitch, String& strMessage) in C:\Dans\Work 2\Working Area\Switch Polling - design 3\Tester apps\ReliableSiteBandwidthPollingTester\ReliableSiteBandwidthPollingTester\Module1.vb:line 427

The polling process:

It interrogates a network switch gathering data. After the interrogation, it then executes a simple stored procedure 105 times which inserts a row into a table each time. It then starts a background thread which executes a "calculation process" stored procedure that uses the table just inserted into as well as other tables. It does inserts into another table - and potentially deletes. A transaction is used. It either commits or rolls back. However, I believe that the procedure does not finish before the next poll begins - the next 30 second mark.

The simple insert stored procedure has been tested stand alone many times and works fine every time.

The "calculation process" stored procedure has been tested stand alone many times and works fine every time.

I start the console app and it it polls 3 times and the fails with that error. Before failing, it writes the out 3 sets of 105 rows to the table. It also inserts 290 rows into another table as part of the  process.

[image]

[image]

```
   Sub PollSwitch(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

    Dim strMessage As String = ""
    Dim strPollError As String = ""
    Dim bPollResult As Boolean
    Dim NetworkSwitch As Switch

    ' This is the format to display as it is how it is stored in the info log table.
    Dim dtFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"

    If bErrorInThread = True Then
        ' There was an error in the background thread during the previous issuance of the thread. So do not continue.
        strMessage = "Critical Error - in the background thread. See the 'BandwidthInfoLog' table. Refer to this log date: " + dtThreadStartDateTime.ToString(dtFormat)
    End If

    If strMessage = "" Then
        ' Create a new instance.
        NetworkSwitch = New Switch(strCommandLineSwitchIP, strCommandLineCommunityString)

        Try
            ' Do the switch polling.
            bPollResult = NetworkSwitch.Poll(strPollError)

            If bPollResult = False Then
                strMessage = "Warning - in bandwidth poll. Poll error at " & Now & ": " & strPollError & " Poll will continue."
            Else
                ' Save to the bandwidth polling log.
                SaveBandwidthPollingLog(NetworkSwitch, strMessage)

                If InStr(strMessage, "Critical") = 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully polled at " & Now() & ".")

                    ' Set the date/time as it will be used above in an error message should the thread process fail.
                    dtThreadStartDateTime = Now()

                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    ' Now do the "calculation process" - it will be in it's own background thread.
                    ' Note: the thread ends when the ProcessCalculatedSwitchPolling method ends.
                    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                    Dim thread As New Thread(AddressOf ProcessCalculatedSwitchPolling)
                    thread.Start()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            strMessage = "Critical Error - in bandwidth poll - " & ex.Message & "<br /><br />Switch: " & strCommandLineSwitchIP
        End Try
    End If

    If InStr(strMessage, "Critical") > 0 Then
        ' Stop this method (this poll timer) as there is a critical error.
        DisposeTimer()

        ' Show message.
        Console.WriteLine(strMessage)
        Console.WriteLine("--------->>>> PRESS ENTER TO QUIT.")
        Console.ReadKey()

        ' Exit the console application here as there is a critical error.
        ' Normally the exit would occur in the main method when the User hits a key.
        Environment.Exit(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

The call stack shows it fails on line 427 which is the .ExecuteNonQuery() line.

```
   Sub SaveBandwidthPollingLog(ByVal SaveSwitch As Switch, ByRef strMessage As String)
    Const strFunctionId As String = "VB - savebandwidthpollinglog. Error ID: "
    Const iSQLErrorId As Integer = 501
    Const iCATCHErrorId As Integer = 502

    Dim dtCurrentDateTime As Date = Now()
    Dim strProcessInfoLogResult As String = ""
    Dim strAdditionalInfoForLog As String = ""

    ' This is the format to display as it is how it is stored in the info log table.
    Dim dtFormat As String = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"

    DBFunc.OpenDB()

    Try
        With DBFunc.objCmd
            .CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "InsertBandwidthLogTest6"
            ' Note: it was timing out, so the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property has expired; the default timeout is 30 seconds.
            .CommandTimeout = 0

            For Each SavePort In SaveSwitch.Port
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SwitchIP", SaveSwitch.IP)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PortIndex", SavePort.Index)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PortSpeed", SavePort.Speed)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@InOctets", SavePort.InOctets)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@OutOctets", SavePort.OutOctets)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", SavePort.TimeStamp)

                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End With
    Catch sqlex As SqlException
        ' Its a critical issue.
        If InStr(sqlex.Message, "Critical") > 0 Then
            ' Coming from the stored procedure.
            strMessage = sqlex.Message
        Else
            strProcessInfoLogResult = ProcessInfoLog(dtCurrentDateTime, sqlex.Message + " --> State: " + sqlex.State.ToString() + " --> Source: " + sqlex.Source + " --> Error number: " + sqlex.Number.ToString() + " --> Line number: " + sqlex.LineNumber.ToString() + " --> Line number: " + sqlex.HResult.ToString() + " --> Class: " + sqlex.Class.ToString() + " --> Procedure: " + sqlex.Procedure + " --> Call stack: " + sqlex.StackTrace, strAdditionalInfoForLog, strFunctionId, iSQLErrorId)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        strProcessInfoLogResult = ProcessInfoLog(dtCurrentDateTime, ex.Message, strAdditionalInfoForLog, strFunctionId, iCATCHErrorId)
    Finally
        ' Close database.
        DBFunc.CloseDB()
    End Try
End Sub
```

The Thread process:

```
    Public Sub ProcessCalculatedSwitchPolling()
    Const strFunctionId As String = "VB - processcalculatedswitchpolling. Error ID: "
    Const iSQLErrorId As Integer = 601
    Const iCATCHErrorId As Integer = 602

    Dim strProcessInfoLogResult As String = ""
    Dim strAdditionalInfoForLog As String = ""
    Dim strInputParms As String = ""

    ' Set for the error log.
    strInputParms = "S/P parmameters - switch IP Address: " & strCommandLineSwitchIP

    DBFunc.OpenDB()

    Try
        With DBFunc.objCmd
            .CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "ProcessBandwidthLogCalculatedTest6"
            ' Note: it was timing out, so the SqlCommand.CommandTimeout property has expired; the default timeout is 30 seconds.
            .CommandTimeout = 0
            .Parameters.Clear()

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@SwitchIP", strCommandLineSwitchIP)

            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    Catch sqlex As SqlException
        ' Its a critical issue.
        If InStr(sqlex.Message, "Critical") > 0 Then
            ' Coming from the stored procedure.
            ' Set the global variable - the thread error indicator.
            bErrorInThread = True
        Else
            ' Not coming from the stored procedure.
            bErrorInThread = True
            ' Log the exception as it was not logged in the stored procedure.
            strAdditionalInfoForLog = strInputParms
            strProcessInfoLogResult = ProcessInfoLog(dtThreadStartDateTime, sqlex.Message, strAdditionalInfoForLog, strFunctionId, iSQLErrorId)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        bErrorInThread = True
        ' Log the exception.
        strAdditionalInfoForLog = strInputParms
        strProcessInfoLogResult = ProcessInfoLog(dtThreadStartDateTime, ex.Message, strAdditionalInfoForLog, strFunctionId, iCATCHErrorId)
    Finally
        ' Close database.
        DBFunc.CloseDB()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: `DBFunc.OpenDB()` Smells.  You should be creating your connection, using your connection, then disposing of your connection when done with it.  Sharing it across threads is also a no-no.  What happens if you ditch the dbfunc stuff and use a SqlConnection like normal?

Comment: DBFunc.OpenDB() and DBFunc.CloseDB() point to class functions that do that work. It gets the connection string from my App.config file. I also tried creating a separate DBFunc.OpenDBThread() and DBFunc.CloseDBThread() for the thread process with its own connection string. It still fails.

Comment: How about getting rid of DBFunc and creating, using and destroying the connection directly?

Comment: I can try that, but keep in mind, it worked fine for 3 consecutive polls before failing. Just not sure what benefit I get by not using the class functions and instead issuing the commands in place of the calls at this point.

Comment: Hey, when you don't know which whirly bit is vibrating, start removing whirly bits until the vibration goes away.  Tear it down to its basics and see if it repros.  If so, you've got bigger issues.

Comment: Ok..I can't disagree with that. But I have a feeling though due to the thread, that a connection is not finishing and getting stepped on as the next one starts. However, I tried increasing the polling span before the next one starts but got the same error.

Comment: We ran a Windows update and did a reboot and it fixed the problem. Thanks to all though for your input.